# Can not display TFS dashboard link in another webpage using iframe

Tags: tfs, dashboard, x-frame-options

On a different domain, I have a simple html page using  embeded TFS dashboard page (on another domain).
Under IIS of TFS page, I have set X-Frame-Options to Allow.

Upon opening the simple html page, I have the following error:
Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, ALLOW').  Failing back to 'deny'.

==> Look like somewhere TFS dashboard page was injected with "SAMEORIGIN".

I look online, people mention about editing Global.asax.cs with setting AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;

Where is that Global.asax.cs?

Comment: I would say: under IIS settings, I have set X-Frame-Options to value: Allow-From http://domainhavingthesimplehtmlpage.

And the error is the following:

Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, Allow-From http://domainhavingthesimplehtmlpage'). Failing back to 'deny'.

Comment: My solution:  Since this is to  display TFS dashboards for  intranet,  I solve this problem by installing a Google extension "Ignore X-Frame-Options" on the Google browser.  The browser ignores X-Frame-Options, so there is no longer sameOrigin issue.